# write jackson objectNode without escape characters

Tags: java, jackson, jsonnode

I wanted to remove escape characters while writing string. My code is as below.

```
private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

public static JsonNode MyMethod()
{
         InputStream cleanUp = TestHelper.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
        message = new String(cleanUp.readAllBytes());

      objectMapper.getFactory().configure(JsonWriteFeature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII.mappedFeature(),false);
      root = objectMapper.readTree(new File("filePath"));

      ((ObjectNode) root).put("message", message );
 
      return root;

}
```

Contain of the `file.txt`

```
[{\n    \"timestamp\": 1599456392538
```

Expected :

```
"[{\n    \"timestamp\": 1599456392538"
```

Actual :

```
"[{\\n    \\\"timestamp\\\": 1599456392538"
```

Comment: Looks like issue happens when get the message from the InputStream, It adds escape characters from there.

Comment: I can use `replace` to remove unwanted characters, but the content could be vary from file to file. So it's bit hacky in tat sense.